# WCF: The issue with using System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message class?

Tags: wcf, message

I'm trying to use WCF service with raw messages.

1) WCF service code:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public static List<Person> CreateEmployees()
{
    List<Person> lstPersons = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "Andrey", LastName = "Andreyev" },
        new Person { Id = 2, FirstName = "Sergey", LastName = "Sergeyev" }
    };

    return lstPersons;
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = TestService.RequestAction, ReplyAction = TestService.ReplyAction)]
    Message GetPersonById(Message id);
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public const String ReplyAction = "http://localhost:4249/Message_ReplyAction";
    public const String RequestAction = "http://localhost:4249/Message_RequestAction";

    public Message GetPersonById(Message id)
    {
        string firstName = Employees.CreateEmployees().First(e => e.Id == id.GetBody<int>()).FirstName;
        Message response = Message.CreateMessage(id.Version, ReplyAction, firstName);
        return response;
    }
}
```

2) Client code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceClient();
    String RequestAction = "http://localhost:4249/Message_RequestAction";
    int value = 1;
    Message request = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Default, RequestAction, value);
    Message reply = client.GetPersonById(request);
    string firstName = reply.GetBody<string>();

    Console.WriteLine(firstName);
    client.Close();
}
```

When I run the client with: int value = 1 everything works fine. But, when I use: int value = 2 I get the following error:

System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException was unhandled
  Message="Error in line 1 position 276. Expecting element 'string' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'Fault', namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'. "
  Source="System.Runtime.Serialization"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.GetBody[T](XmlObjectSerializer serializer)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.GetBodyT
       at ClientTestService.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\Projekti\WCF\Parus\ClientTestService\ClientTestService\Program.cs:line 22
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:

At line:

```
string firstName = reply.GetBody<string>();
```

The service is started and I've added the service reference through "Add Service Reference..." in VS2008. I use .NET Framework 3.5.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

When I don't use Message class everything works fine. I mean on this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Person GetPersonById(int id);
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public Person GetPersonById(int id)
    {
        Person person = Employees.CreateEmployees().First(e => e.Id == id);
        return person;
    }
}
```

2) Client code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceClient();
    int value = 1;
    Person person = client.GetPersonById(value);

    Console.WriteLine(person.FirstName);
    client.Close();
}
```

I would be really thankful if somebody can help.

Comment: In the end I've found the reason why error message comes up. It is because the message has been read. It means it can read the list with items only first time and that's why it works with 1. But, how can I overcome this situation with using List on server side? I've read about MessageBuffer, but don't know how to apply it in my situation. Where should I write MessageBuffer code on server or on client side and what to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Message reply = client.GetPersonById(request); 
if(reply.IsFault)
  throw new GoransException(reply.toString());
string firstName = reply.GetBody<string>();
//...
```

Comment: In the end I've found the reason why error message comes up. It is because the message has been read. It means it can read the list with items only first time and that's why it works with 1. But, how can I overcome this situation with using List on server side? I've read about MessageBuffer, but don't know how to apply it in my situation. Where should I write MessageBuffer code on server or on client side and what to write?